# How do I Make an executable Lua script using srlua?

Tags: lua

My main goal is to either make my lua file into executable or make it into a bite code.
preferably both of them.
I am trying srlua,but in readme file it tells me to do:

"For Windows, you need to create srlua.exe and glue.exe first. Then for each
Lua program that you want to turn into a stand-alone program, do
    glue srlua.exe prog.lua prog.exe
Of course, you can use any name instead of prog.exe."

and when I am trying to compile it using codebluck to get(srlua.exe),I get this :[image]

and what dose it mean by this?
glue srlua.exe prog.lua prog.exe
where should I type that it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where have you installed Lua? In particular, where are its header files?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1

Comment: Are you sure about `void *data` as an argument?

Comment: The issue come from the compiler not being able to find the Lua headers as lhf hinted. These should be set either in the project settings or put next to the `srlua.c` file. The particular error you highlighted in the image is caused by the fact that the compiler can't find the `lua_State` struct (again - because the headers that define it are nowhere to be found).

Answer (score 2):

Type it into your shell. Once you have the binary of srlua, that takes "prog.lua" and glues it to "srlua.exe" making "prog.exe". Of course, you need glue as well. You can get an srlua binary and a glue binary for Lua 5.1 here. http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#srlua