# How to compile srlua (or a link to the binaries)

Tags: windows, lua, compilation

> Related:
> [How to compile srlua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642852/how-to-compile-srlua) 
> [How do I Make an executable Lua script using srlua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815348/how-do-i-make-an-executable-lua-script-using-srlua)

The first link is the exact question I am asking here. However, the sole answer is unsatisfactory as it assumes multiple things, namely that the OP is already using Cmake (a fact disproved by the OP's comment on the answer). The second link seems to already be most of the way through a tutorial, and while a link to precompiled binaries for both srlua.exe and srglue.exe are provided, the link no longer contains binaries but instead the source.

I have found several other threads on various websites all asking the same thing, but all of them either assume that you essentially already know how, or explain nothing (many have potentially helpful links, but they are old and no longer work).

I have already tried to compile srlua, and got a srglue.exe, but when I tried srlua.c I ended up with a list of undefined references (such as "lua_type" or "lua_getfield").

```
lua_getfield,  lua_type,  lua_settop,  lua_getfield,  lua_type,  lua_settop,  lua_pushstring,  lua_pushinteger,  lua_call,  lua_pushfstring,  lua_load,  lua_tolstring,  lua_tointeger,  lua_touserdata,  luaL_openlibs,  lua_createtable,  lua_pushstring,  lua_rawseti,  lua_setfield,  luaL_checkstack,  lua_pushstring,  lua_call,  lua_tolstring,  luaL_callmeta,  lua_type,  lua_type,  lua_typename,  lua_pushfstring,  luaL_newstate,  lua_pushcclosure,  lua_pushcclosure,  lua_pushinteger,  lua_pushlightuserdata,  lua_pcall,  lua_tolstring,  lua_close
```

**My question is this:**
How does one use a C compiler (I know the basics of `gcc`) to compile srlua specifically? Or, if anyone has a functioning link to either precompiled binaries or a tool to compile the binaries, could they share it?

**Important**: I am on Windows. Thus, I cannot just use `make`. I must actually compile the .c files to .exe files. I am asking how. If you simply provide links to threads with the aforementioned problems, you are not helping. If you give an answer that assumes in-depth prior knowledge of a particular tool that does not have good documentation, you are not being helpful. If you tell me tools to use, but not the specific procedure for compiling srlua, you are not being helpful. If there is a better place for this, tell me and I can move it there.

Comment: You need to link  srlua.obj with a Lua library. If you have a Lua library as a DLL, you probably need to have that DLL in the same folder. I'm sorry I cannot give you more precise instructions for Windows.

Comment: I don't have a srlua.obj. Am I supposed to make that from the srlua.c?

Comment: What gcc command line are you using?

Comment: I was using TDM-GCC (not Mingw).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any Windows pre-compiled binaries for srLua.

To compile srLua, you should first install the Mingw compiler to use GCC as a C compiler : you can install TDM-GCC (https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc) or http://winlibs.com.

You can then open a Console prompt. Enter the "gcc" command to be sure that the compiler is working (and that the PATH is correctly set).

Then go to the directory you extracted the srLua source files and type the command :

```
mingw32-make
```

Cross your fingers and it should compile everything :)

When linking, you should include the Lua libraries with the -l Switch : -llua54 for Lua 5.4 library for examples.

Comment: Ok, so when I do `mingw-make ./srglue`, I get srglue.exe. All is well. However, doing the same for `./srlua` results in the same errors I got before (undefined references). I don't feel like manually copying all of the hundreds of Lua library files (many of which have conflicting names) over into my srlua directory, nor linking every single one, so is there a way in the Makefile to link to the libraries? I already edited the Makefile to give it my Lua directory and copied all of /lib and /include over.

Comment: You are right. The provided Makefile is only targetting Unix systems, hence the error. You have to modify the line LUA= with the path where you have unpacked the Lua archive. Then remove the -ldl  switch on the line LIBS= and replace -llua with -llua54. Finally remove the line chmod +x, the clean line and the rm line.

Comment: Even after all those steps (I had already rectified the paths), I get the same "undefined reference" errors. Could it be a problem with the install "function"?

Answer (score 0):

I found this already compiled release on webarchive, it's kinda old but works:
https://web.archive.org/web/20130721014948/http://www.soongsoft.com/lhf/lua/5.1/srlua.tgz

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30176446)

Comment: Thanks! I think the above comment was automated, as the comment is a workaround, and the issue seems unresolveable.